# How to avoid setting ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS for setup-python?

Tags: github-actions

Github Actions' `actions/setup-python` step doesn't succeed due to the use of `::set-env:` and `::add-path:`, that are blocked because considered as insecure (https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands).

Succeed by setting `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS=true` environment variable for this step.

How to avoid allowing unsecure commands to successfully run a Python build?

---

Self-hosted runner in a custom-built docker with Ubuntu 20.04 base image. Linked to an GHE server v2.22.4.

Tried with both Python 3.9.0 and 3.9.1

Workflow file:

```
name: CD testing
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
    runs-on: [ Linux ]

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: setup python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.9.0

    - name: execute py script
      run: |
        python -V
```

```
##[debug]Found tool in cache Python 3.9.1 x64
::set-env name=pythonLocation::/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.1/x64
##[error]Unable to process command '::set-env name=pythonLocation::/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.1/x64' successfully.
##[error]The `set-env` command is disabled. Please upgrade to using Environment Files or opt into unsecure command execution by setting the `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS` environment variable to `true`. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/
##[debug]System.Exception: The `set-env` command is disabled. Please upgrade to using Environment Files or opt into unsecure command execution by setting the `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS` environment variable to `true`. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/
##[debug]   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.SetEnvCommandExtension.ProcessCommand(IExecutionContext context, String line, ActionCommand command, ContainerInfo container)
##[debug]   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionCommandManager.TryProcessCommand(IExecutionContext context, String input, ContainerInfo container)
::add-path::/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.1/x64
##[error]Unable to process command '::add-path::/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.1/x64' successfully.
##[error]The `add-path` command is disabled. Please upgrade to using Environment Files or opt into unsecure command execution by setting the `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS` environment variable to `true`. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/
##[debug]System.Exception: The `add-path` command is disabled. Please upgrade to using Environment Files or opt into unsecure command execution by setting the `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS` environment variable to `true`. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/
##[debug]   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.AddPathCommandExtension.ProcessCommand(IExecutionContext context, String line, ActionCommand command, ContainerInfo container)
##[debug]   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionCommandManager.TryProcessCommand(IExecutionContext context, String input, ContainerInfo container)
::add-path::/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.1/x64/bin
##[error]Unable to process command '::add-path::/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.1/x64/bin' successfully.
##[error]The `add-path` command is disabled. Please upgrade to using Environment Files or opt into unsecure command execution by setting the `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS` environment variable to `true`. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/
##[debug]System.Exception: The `add-path` command is disabled. Please upgrade to using Environment Files or opt into unsecure command execution by setting the `ACTIONS_ALLOW_UNSECURE_COMMANDS` environment variable to `true`. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/
##[debug]   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.AddPathCommandExtension.ProcessCommand(IExecutionContext context, String line, ActionCommand command, ContainerInfo container)
##[debug]   at GitHub.Runner.Worker.ActionCommandManager.TryProcessCommand(IExecutionContext context, String input, ContainerInfo container)
::set-output name=python-version::3.9.1
##[debug]='3.9.1'
Successfully setup CPython (3.9.1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Update `actions/setup-python` which uses `set-env` in previous versions from

```
- uses: actions/setup-python@v2
```

to the latest version

```
- uses: actions/setup-python@v2.2.1
```

There's a [bug](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/183) - `v2` does not use the latest version.